# Prepared Statement in mysql through excel VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, prepared-statement, string-concatenation

I have worked on a prepared statement in Mysql, which dynamically creates week columns based on the current date. It works seamlessly when I run the query in Toad for Mysql, I'm having enormous problems running the query when I am trying to convert the query to a string in VBA......I get an error stating I have a problem with the syntax near etc with the sql. The error is created in every part of the sql despite the fact the string looks fine. I subbed in  for " with chr(34), or ' with chr(39) and still I get an error with the sql syntax. I have also tried to avoid these string problems by importing the code below which imports the .sql file to no avail.

```
    Sub TopAway()
    Dim Cnn As Object
    Dim Rst As Object
    Dim ConnectionString, SqlTextFile, SqlStatement As String
    Set Cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A2:T3000").ClearContents

    ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server =  10.1.1.201; Database = cms; Uid = root; Pwd = something;"

   Cnn.Open ConnectionString
   Cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

   SqlTextFile = "C:\Users\adam\Desktop\WORK FOLDER\Tony Project\Analysis Projects\Away_No_Stock\Dynamic_Away.sql"
   Debug.Print SqlTextFile
   Dim hFile As Long
   hFile = FreeFile
   Open SqlTextFile For Input As #hFile
   SqlStatement = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
   Close #hFile
   Debug.Print SqlStatement

   Rst.Open SqlStatement, Cnn '<-- This is where the code fails

   Sheets("Summary").Range("B3").CopyFromRecordset Rst
   End Sub
```

The SQL code is below.....

```
    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT("SUM(IF((part_id IN (265,302,647) OR notes REGEXP ('away|unfit|unavailable|bus away|night')) && WEEKOFYEAR(job_engineerdate) = '", WEEKOFYEAR(job_engineerdate) , "' , 1 ,0)) AS '", WEEKOFYEAR(job_engineerdate), "'")
    )
    INTO @answers
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT (job_engineerdate)
    FROM job j                          
    ORDER BY (job_engineerdate) ASC
    ) A
    WHERE job_engineerdate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 112 DAY AND job_engineerdate <= CURDATE();


    SET @query =  CONCAT("SELECT customer_name, garage_name, ", @answers, " 
    FROM (
    SELECT c.customer_name, g.garage_name, j.id, jp.part_id, jn.notes, j.job_engineerdate

    FROM job j 
    INNER JOIN vehicle v ON j.job_vehicleid = v.id 
    INNER JOIN garage g ON v.garage_id = g.id 
    INNER JOIN customer c ON g.customer_id = c.id 
    INNER JOIN fault_type ft ON j.job_fault = ft.id
    INNER JOIN job_parts jp ON j.id = jp.job_id 
    INNER JOIN part p ON p.id = jp.part_id 
    INNER JOIN job_notes jn ON j.id = jn.job_id 
    INNER JOIN users u ON j.job_engineer = u.id         

    WHERE
    c.customer_group IN (13) AND
    j.deleted = 0 
    AND j.job_engineerdate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 112 DAY

    GROUP BY
    v.vehicle_fleet_number, v.id, j.id, jp.part_id, jn.id

    ORDER BY customer_name, garage_name
    ) AS T
    GROUP BY customer_name, garage_name
    ORDER BY 18 DESC
    LIMIT 15") 
    ;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I have no idea how to get this working through excel, if anybody has any ideas, it would be very much appreciated!! I have spent a long time looking on the web for answers but have not been able to find any solutions to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know MySql in detail, but I am almost sure that your problem is the the SQL is not a sinlge SQL-Select statement but a Script that contains several statements.

Answer (score 0):

I tackle also with this kind of problem how to translate an sql prepared statement in Excel (VBA), finally I went through with writing a routine in VBA to build the same sql statement as it would be build by the prepared statement. 
At the end a prepared statement is a "procedure" you should have no problem translating it in a VBA code.
Hope it helps you (even if I didn't manage to write the VBA code relevant to your case)...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. It was just creating the column headers in VBA and then adding those to the sql string with variable date inputs. Much easier than trying to do it with a prepared statement. Thanks for your response, it took me a long time to see it!